# Enable nmblookup during ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: 16.04, boot, server, xubuntu, debian-installer

I want to be able to run nmblookup during debian installer shell script (d-i preseed/include_command ....). 
How can I modify ISO to have nmblookup (it's included with SAMBA) enabled?
I have already tried CUBIC but it didn't work. I also tried to manually mount the ISO, chroot, unpack, install packages, repack and create ISO, didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to my problem. Follow the link
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145621/debian-installer-customize-busybox-and-live-system-environment

You can customize the booting enviroment (build with busybox), adding to it's minimal set of commands your own. You have to  do it manually, putting all binary files and libraries to their proper folders.